# what's the difference between code=1 and code=2 in EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am receiving code=1 or code=2 for EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I am wondering what's the difference between code=1 and code=2?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Code = 1 is KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS and code = 2 is KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE. Both are
explained in the ["Technical Note TN2123 CrashReporter"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html#SECCRASHLOGEXCEPTION):

> The most common forms of exception are:
>
> - EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS — This is caused by the thread
>     accessing unmapped memory. It may be triggered by either a data access
>     or an instruction fetch; the Thread State section describes how to
>     tell the difference.
> - EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE — This is
>     caused by the thread trying to write to read-only memory. This is
>     always caused by a data access.

The codes are defined in [`<mach/kern_return.h>`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.0.2/osfmk/mach/kern_return.h):

```
#define KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS            1
                /* Specified address is not currently valid.
                 */

#define KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE         2
                /* Specified memory is valid, but does not permit the
                 * required forms of access.
                 */
```

and in [`<mach/exception_types.h>`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.0.2/osfmk/mach/exception_types.h) it is documented that the code 
for a EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a `kern_return_t`:

```
#define EXC_BAD_ACCESS          1       /* Could not access memory */
                /* Code contains kern_return_t describing error. */
                /* Subcode contains bad memory address. */
```

Comment: In Unix terms, it's the same distinction as SIGBUS and SIGSEGV.